# Android Audio Streaming Very Slow

Tags: android, streaming, shoutcast

I am developing an android audio streaming application. I am using androids mediaplayer prepareAsync() in my service class.

However the streaming is very slow in Android 2.3 gingerbread. It works fine on Android 2.2 and 4.0 (around 5-6 seconds), but takes around 80 seconds on 2.3.

Is there any alternative radio streaming client that i can use.

I am referring Android Random Music Player Code for this application development.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ListenAudio extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       //specify the url of audio file
        String path = ?;

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
        mediaPlayer.start();

            }}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's just vanilla MediaPlayer stuff.